# LibGDX: Implement touch screen, without touching the screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touchscreen

I'm using LibGDX.

Let's say that I wan't to jump - but not really touching the screen, I don't want to use a keyboard forsay, And implement the touch, like i was touching the screen.
Can i do that?

Can one let's say "test" the button without pressing it (from the touch screen of application / android / ios / etc..)?

Example of a button from InputListener:

```
final Image imageJumpButton = new Image(new Texture("jbjump.png"));
imageJumpButton.addListener(new InputListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        JOYSTICK_UP= true;
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        JOYSTICK_UP = false;
    }
});
```

I thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Button` class for a button instead of `Image`. There is a convenient way to do what you ask with `Button`:

```
final Button imageJumpButton = new Button(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("jbjump.png"))));
//use ChangeListener instead of InputListener
imageJumpButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Gdx.app.log("", "Button is pressed");
        }
    });
```

Then you could programmatically press the button:

```
//this will trigger changed() method of the ChangeListener
imageJumpButton.toggle();
```

**Update**

If you want to do something, while the button is pressed, call this in your `render()` method:

```
if (button.isPressed())
    //do something each frame, while button is pressed
```

For example, if you want a player to run, while the button is pressed, it would be something like this:

```
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    if (button.isPressed())
        player.x += deltaTime * velocityX;
}
```

And by the way, you don't need to add ChangeListener to the button in this case.

Comment: I need to use this Button in a way that: while hold, do something, while not holding, don't do anything. e.g button for running. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably. I'm not sure if this working. Can't test now. You can use Actor `fire(Event event)` method.

```
imageJumpButton.fire(InputEvent.Type.touchDown);
```

or

```
imageJumpButton.fire(InputEvent.Type.touchUp);
```